# C Function is null inside array, but works when called directly

Tags: c, makefile, lua

I have a folder of C files that are compiled into one library and linked together, then required with Lua from a C++ program.

```
CFLAGS = -std=c++17 -ggdb -O0
LDFLAGS = -llua -lrgl -lfreetype

SRC = -c src/luargl/*.c
OBJ = metasprite.o luargl.o

# luargl.o is deleted before running app
all: compile link main

compile:
    gcc -Iinclude -fPIC -Wall $(SRC) 

link:
    gcc $(OBJ) -shared -o luargl.so $(LDFLAGS)

main:
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o app src/main.cpp $(LDFLAGS)
```

Inside luargl.c, I have some problematic code:

```
LUALIB_API int luaopen_luargl(lua_State* L) {
    state = L;

    printf("Functions: %s, %s\n", luargl_sprite_methods[0].func, luargl_sprite_methods[0].name);
    luargl_sprite_index(state);
...
```

with output:

```
// Functions: (null), (null)
// sprite index
```

The functions are defined inside metasprite.c and included with metasprite.h:

```
int luargl_sprite_index(lua_State* state) {
    printf("sprite index\n");
    return 0;
}

int luargl_sprite_newindex(lua_State* state) {
    printf("sprite newindex\n");
    return 0;
}

static const luaL_Reg luargl_sprite_methods[] = {
    { "__index", luargl_sprite_index},
    { "__newindex", luargl_sprite_newindex},

    { NULL, NULL }
};
```

Why can I call the function but have it stay null when it's inside of the array? Further, how can I get the array to have the contents of what is described in metasprite.c?

Comment: Why exactly are you printing function pointers using `%s`? That doesn't make any sense at all. Did you mean to call a function returning a character pointer?

Comment: Name is a string. I was comparing ...[0].func == NULL earlier and printing a boolean but it got mixed up. That being said, func == NULL is true which is a problem.

Comment: How do you expect to access the table that is defined in `metasprite.c` from your function in `luargl.c`? That array is static. Whatever you think you do, you seem to access another array.

Comment: That is one of the reasons why you should post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). With those tiny snippets we cannot see what you really are doing.

Comment: Also even if you check `func == null` (which the code you show us, does not!) it will still not work to print a function pointer using `%s` format specifier in case `fund!=null`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to fixate on what i'm putting inside printf. It would have at least changed behaviour from printing "null", which is all I needed for testing if it works.

Comment: You are printing `luargl_sprite_methods[0].func` with `%s` which is complete nonsense and undefined behavior. If your program contains undefined behavior somewhere, then completely different, unrelated parts of the program might crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array is *static*, i. e. unless you provide access by other means (e.g. function returning pointers into) it is only accessible from within that file:

```
// metasprite.c (!)

   static const luaL_Reg luargl_sprite_methods[] = { ... };
// ^^^^^^  (!!!)
```

Thus the array is *not* visible from within `luargl.c`.

You haven't provided the header, but you must have written it in a way such that this latter file gets its own version of the array.

If you need access to such array from multiple files then you need to handle the matter differently!

```
// metasprite.h:

extern luaL_Reg const luargl_sprite_methods[3];
//                                          ^
// unfortunately no way to get around specifying size explicitly

// metasprite.c:

luaL_Reg const luargl_sprite_methods[] { ... };
// note: NO static!
```

A `#define` might help to avoid array size collisions, but the problem remains. Though as the array is null-terminated anyway you might instead better get away with a pointer:

```
// metasprite.h:

extern luaL_Reg const* luargl_sprite_methods;
//                   ^

// metasprite.c:

static luaL_Reg const luargl_sprite_methods_[] { ... };
// NOW can be static, but needs a different name!

luaL_Reg const* luargl_sprite_methods = luargl_sprite_methods_;
// again: NO static!
```

Iteration would then occur profiting from exactly that:

```
for(luaL_Reg const* l = luargl_sprite_methods; l->key; ++l)
{
   // use l->func
}
```

Comment: I didn't know static worked this way. Thanks.